# How to make assertions inside a promise when any errors thrown don't bubble up?

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, throw

Running this with mocha results in timing out, rather than letting mocha catch the error so it could fail immediately..

```
var when = require('when');
var should = require('should');

describe('', function() {
    it('', function(done) {
        var d = when.defer();
        d.resolve();
        d.promise.then(function() {
            true.should.be.false;
            false.should.be.true;
            throw new Error('Promise');
            done();
}); }); });
```

<sup>http://runnable.com/me/U7VmuQurokZCvomD</sup>

Is there another way to make assertions inside the promise, such that when they fail they are caught by mocha causing it to fail immediately?

---

As per chai recommendation, I looked into it and it seems I have to have a direct access to the promise object, right? The problem is that I'm not using promise *directly*.. My bad if I simplified but This would be a more closer to reality example

```
function core_library_function(callback){
    do_something_async(function which_returns_a(promise){
        promise.then(function(){
            callback(thing);
}); }); }

describe('', function() {
    it('', function(done) {
        core_library_function(function(thing){
            ...
            done();                         
}); }); });
```

So I really have no control over the promise directly, it's abstracted far far away.

Comment: Consider chai as promised

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using promises with Mocha, you'll have to `return` the promise in the test and will want to remove the `done` parameter since the callback isn't being used.

```
it('', function() {
    var d = when.defer();
    d.resolve();
    return d.promise.then(function() {
        throw new Error('Promise');
    });
});
```

This is described in the docs under [Working with Promises](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises):

> Alternately, instead of using the `done()` callback, you can return a promise.

Comment: I also found that the `catch()` function called at the very end worked equally well, calling `done()` inside and passing it the error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40563588/88111